# Memory manipulating - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, character, memcpy

Right, so I'm playing around with memory moving data around. I'm having trouble here.
What can I be doing wrong? I've accounted for the null terminator and it still doesn't output what I expect.

```
char buff[34] = "I will not do anything like that.";
char * protocol = "abcdefghi";

char data[44];

memcpy(data, protocol, 10);
memcpy(data + 9, buff, 34);

cout << data << endl; //abcdefghiI will not do anything like that.
cout << strlen(data) << endl; // 42

char poin[10];
memcpy(poin, data, 10);

cout << poin << endl; //abcdefghiI╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠abcdefghiI will not do anything like that.
```

For the last cout I was expecting just abcdefghi, but it comes out as you see above.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would not recommend using strcpy for copying strings in C++, but using memcpy for it is a whole other level of C with Classes. I'll suggest a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642

Comment: Btw, the answer is as simple as "no, you have not accounted for the null terminator"

Answer (score 1):

`poin` is not a `'\0'`-terminated string. You overwrote the first `'\0'` with `'I'` here:

```
memcpy(data + 9, buff, 34);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `poin` is not null-terminated.
You copied the beginning 10 bytes of `data` into `poin`, so now

```
poin[0] == 'a'
poin[1] == 'b'
poin[2] == 'c'
poin[3] == 'd'
poin[4] == 'e'
poin[5] == 'f'
poin[6] == 'g'
poin[7] == 'h'
poin[8] == 'i'
poin[9] == 'I'
```

Then, `std::cout` went outside the array `poin`'s boundary, and the values in those addresses are indeed unknown.

Answer (score 0):

The last `memcpy` doesn't include the `'\0'` used to terminate C style strings.

You would be much better off using `strcpy`, or when using C++ - `std::string`.